# Passing parameter to command in powershell

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

Could you tell my why this works:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName xxx, yyy, zzz -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object pscomputername, @{Name="Size GB";Expression={ "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}}, @{Name="Free GB";Expression={ "{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB) }}
```

And this is not:

```
$Machines = "xxx, yyyy, zzz"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Machines -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object pscomputername, @{Name="Size GB";Expression={ "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}}, @{Name="Free GB";Expression={ "{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB) }}
```

?

I'm really confused.
I tried to change $Machines to:

```
xxx, yyy, zzz
@(xxx, yyy, zzz)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
>   At C:\AppSupport\ps\freespace\freespace.ps1:10 char:1
>   + Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Machines -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is

```
$Machines = @("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")
```

which will pass them as an array.

Comment: Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined all three names as a single string.

```
$Machines = "xxx, yyyy, zzz"
```

This is the same as calling `Get-WmiObject` for the computer `"xxx, yyyy, zzz"`

`xxx, yyy, zzz` and `@(xxx, yyy, zzz)` doesn't work because you didn't quote them, so PowerShell tries to use them as an expression and save the results (calling the function/cmdlet/application with name `xxx` etc.). That's why it returns ex.

```
$machines = xxx, yyy, zzz
At line:1 char:16
+ $machines = xxx, yyy, zzz
+                ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

You need to split them into an array of three strings. This should work

```
$Machines = "xxx", "yyyy", "zzz"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Machines -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" |
Select-Object pscomputername, @{Name="Size GB";Expression={ "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}}, @{Name="Free GB";Expression={ "{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB) }}
```

Comment: Many Thanks! that worked and I understand what i have done wrong.